# i am trying to generate HMAC-SHA1 Signature for Oauth 1.0a

Tags: php, etrade-api

I am trying to make a function that generate HMAC-SHA1 signature but getting an error (invalid_signature)

My source code is

```
public function generateSignature($request, $timestamp, $nonce, $signatureMethod, $version, $consumerKey, $consumerSecret)
{
    $base = $request['method'] . "&" . rawurlencode($request['url']) . "&"
    . rawurlencode("oauth_consumer_key=" . rawurlencode($consumerKey)
    . "&oauth_nonce=" . rawurlencode($nonce)
    . "&oauth_signature_method=" . rawurlencode($signatureMethod)
    . "&oauth_timestamp=" . rawurlencode($timestamp)
    . "&oauth_version=" . rawurlencode($version));

    $key = rawurlencode($consumerSecret);
    $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base, $key, true));

    return $signature;
}
```

it works perfectly on postman with the values used in the function but not by using this function.
I am trying to generate signature for E-Trade Api

```
https://api.etrade.com/oauth/request_token
```

Thanks in advance.